# SQL: I want to compare three rows of data based on a criterion and identify the one with the lowest value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an inspection table that shows the serial number, the inspection (Characteristic), and the test result (TestValue). In the sample table, I show five inspections for each serial number, but for a set of inspections I need to find the one that has the lowest value. I actually need the absolute value of `90` minus the TESTVALUE and identify the lowest decimal result. I did not include that calculation in my sample table. I have tried several different methods, but they have ultimately failed due to the fact that they do not take into account multiple criteria but only needing this calculation on a specific set.

This data goes into a report and I tried doing this in Report Builder and did not fair any better.

TABLE: Inspections
COLUMNS: Serial, Characteristic, TestValue

[image: Sample Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, please provide sample data as text, not an image.

Please note the `left(Characteristic,5)` ... this may be an issue down the line

Perhaps this will help

```
Select * 
      ,MinValue =  TestValue 
                  * case when sum(1) over (partition by Serial,left(Characteristic,5)) > 1 then 1 end
                  * case when TestValue = min(TestValue) over (partition by Serial,left(Characteristic,5)) then 1 end
 From YourTable
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, John.  This worked for me and simple too.  As for the image, this was my first post and it automatically changed my text sample to an image.

Comment: @DavidLopez In the future, you will get more attention if the sample data is in text form.  Few are willing to do the required data entry.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when looking for the lowest value within a group I would suggest using a `ROW_NUMBER` function to identify the rows you are interested in. However, in this case, a subquery seems like a good alternative.

The subquery would be something like this:

```
select serial, min(testvalue) as mintestvalue
from table
where characteristic like 'Angle%'
group by serial
```

Now you have the appropriate test values you wanted for each serial number. Left-join this subquery to the dataset on `serial` number to have the `mintestvalue` column included in your dataset.